# WooCommerce REST API передача массива

Tags: php, json, rest

Пытаюсь добавить товар при помощи WooCommerce REST API, так сказать - снаружи, POST-запросом. Все шло нормально, пока не понадобилось соотносить товар с группой. Ибо группа передается массивом.

Вот так все работает. Авторизация ОК. Добавляется товар с названием из `$params['name']`

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $params['oauth_consumer_key'],
    'oauth_nonce' => $params['oauth_nonce'],
    'oauth_signature_method' => $params['oauth_signature_method'], 
    'oauth_signature' => rawurlencode($signature),
    'oauth_timestamp' => $params['oauth_timestamp'], 
    'oauth_version' => $params['oauth_version'],

    'name' => ($params['name'])

] );
```

Но если я пытаюсь таким же образом добавить группу

```
$params = array(
         ...
        'name' => 'Good 3',
        'categories' => '{"0":{"id":"21"}}'
    );
```

То получаю сообщение

> {"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Неверный параметр: categories","data":{"status":400,"params":{"categories":"categories[0] не принадлежит к типу object."}}}

Я как только не группировал эти скобки для `categories`. И фигурные и квадратные, и с индексом и без. Пробовал добавлять заголовок `Accept: application/json` - ошибка та же.

Подскажите, кто знает.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А почему именно json передача? попробуйте массивом `=> [0 => ['id' => 21]]`

Comment: Ровно та же ошибка...

Comment: Попробуйте передать туда не JSON сериализованную строку, а сам объект. Для вас это будет  'categories' => json_decode('{"0":{"id":"21"}}'). Ну и не забудьте про Content-Type: application/json, Accept это заголовок ответа, а не запроса. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284176/how-can-i-post-json-object-through-curl-in-php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, `json_decode` это вроде в другую сторону... Я попробовал `json_decode` - ошибка (объект вместо строки), попробовал `json_encode` - появилась все та же ошибка. `Content-Type: application/json` - у меня не только жсон, есть еще данные авторизации, идущие классическим способом

Comment: @DNS, а по документации пробовали отсылать запрос? (https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#create-a-product) Насколько я вижу туда передаётся обычный массив с цифрами категорий, а не JSON строка. Да, и уточните версию API, пожалуйста.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, конечно я изучал этот ресурс. Но он создает впечатление само-обращения - вызываем АПИ из самого ВП. В этом смысле все намного проще - позволена базовая авторизация, можно использовать методы объекта `woocommerce`. Мне надо достучаться извне. По НТТР. Версия АПИ - `v2`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $products_array = array(
            "product" => array(
                "title" => $realname,
                "body_html" => "<strong>$message</strong>",
                "vendor" => $prod,
                "product_type" => $type,
               "images" => array(array(
                   "src" => "/uploads/" . $name
               )),
                "published" => true,
                "variants" => array(
                    array(
                        "sku" => "t_009",
                        "price" => $Money,
                        "grams" => $gram,
                        "taxable" => false,

                    )
                ),
            ),
        );
//        echo json_encode($products_array);
//        echo "<br />";
        $url = "https://$shopifyapi:$shoppassword@$shop/admin/products.json";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($products_array));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//        $response =
        curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

надо просто без ошибок переходить от json  на массив вот мой  пример `{
  "product": {
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
 "images":{["src":"http://test.loc/uploads/IrB0R2RrLM8MOsDHZv03ABjLW58vNeitiMXVPpRO.jpeg"]}
    "variants": [
      {
        "option1": "First",
        "price": "10.00",
        "sku": "123"
      },
      {
        "option1": "Second",
        "price": "20.00",
        "sku": "123"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: Это у Вас базовая авторизация? У меня ниже OAuth не пускает. А для нее надо формировать подпись данных, обязательно включая метку времени. Из-за этой-то подписи все проблемы и вылазят. Давалась бы базовая - и вопроса бы не было